longtables is breaking my document
I am trying to embed the following longtable into my document. I am running Tex Live within a docker container, and using Latex Workshop in VS code. The chapter containing the longtable:
\chapter{Deployment and Coverage Analysis}
\label{chap:deployment_analysis}
% Content for Deployment Analysis

\section{Ressource Allocation}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item \sout{Resource and apparatus allocation chart}
    \item resource map
\end{enumerate}

\section{Deployment}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item engine Coverage
    \item station coverage overlap
    \item truck Coverage
    \item response time dot map
\end{enumerate}

\todo{this might not fit in this chapter}

\begin{longtable}{lll}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Station} & \textbf{Apparatus} & \textbf{Staffing Details} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Station} & \textbf{Apparatus} & \textbf{Staffing Details} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \midrule \multicolumn{3}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot

    \bottomrule
    \caption{Staffing and Apparatus Allocation for Fire Stations} \\
    \endlastfoot

    Future Airport & N/A & No Engine or Ladder \\
    \midrule
    Station 1 & E01, L01 & 6 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 3 Captains, 1 Battalion Chief \\
    Station 2 & E02, L02 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 3 & E03, TW03 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 4 & E04, L04 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 5 & E05 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 6 & E06 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 7 & E07 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 8 & E08 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 9 & E09 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 10 & E10, R10 & 5 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains, 1 Battalion Chief \\
    Station 11 & E11, R11 & 5 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 12 & E12 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 13 & L13, E13 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 14 & E14 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 15 & E15 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 16 & E16, L16 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 17 & E17 & 3 Firefighters, 1 Blaze FF, 1 Blaze Company Officer, 1 Blaze Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 18 & E18, TW18 & 3 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 19 & E19 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 20 & E20 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain, 1 Battalion Chief \\
    Station 21 & E21 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 22 & E22 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 23 & L23, E23 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 24 & L24, E24 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 25 & E25 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain, 1 Battalion Chief \\
    Station 26 & L26, E26 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 27 & L27, E27 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains, 1 Battalion Chief \\
    Station 28 & E28, L28 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 29 & E29 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 30 & E30 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 31 & E31, L31 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 32 & L32, E32 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 33 & L33, E33 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 34 & E34 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 35 & E35 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 36 & E36 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 37 & E37 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 38 & E38 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
    Station 39 & E39 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain, 1 Battalion Chief \\
    Station 40 & L40, E40 & 4 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains \\
    Station 41 & E41 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain, 2 Blaze Firefighters, 3 Blaze Engineers, 2 Blaze Company Officers \\
    Station 42 & E42, E65 & 3 Firefighters, 2 Engineers, 2 Captains, 1 Battalion Chief \\
    Station 43 & E43 & 2 Firefighters, 1 Engineer, 1 Captain \\
\end{longtable}

\todo{Fix this allignment}

Here is my compiler output:
> Rc files read:   /etc/LatexMk Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins,
> 29 September 2020, version: 4.70b. Rule 'bibtex main': File changes,
> etc:    No-longer-existing files:
>       'main.aux'
> ------------ Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex main'
> ------------
> ------------ Running 'bibtex  "main.aux"'
> ------------ Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex main'... For rule 'bibtex main', running '&run_bibtex(  )' ... I couldn't open file name
> `main.aux' Latexmk: Bibtex did not produce 'main.bbl'.  But that
>      was because of missing files, so I will continue. Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:    No-longer-existing files:
>       'main.aux'
>       'main.out'
> ------------ Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
> ------------
> ------------ Running 'pdflatex  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder  "/app/report/main.tex"'
> ------------ Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'... This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded
> format=pdflatex)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
> (/app/report/main.tex LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4 L3
> programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls Document
> Class: report 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty For
> additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty Excluding
> comment 'comment')
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titling/titling.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocloft/tocloft.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/footmisc/footmisc.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshadows.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfadings.code.tex
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfadings.code.tex)))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
> No file main.aux.
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] )
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
> *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
> *geometry* detected driver: pdftex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty)
> 
> Package todonotes Warning: The length marginparwidth is less than 2cm
> and will most likely cause issues with the appearance of inserted
> todonotes. The issue can be solved by adding a line like \setlength
> {\marginparwidth }{2cm} prior to loading the todonotes package. on
> input line 65.
> 
> (./titlepage.tex [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
> </app/graphics/Charlotte_Logo.png> </app/graphics/Levrum Logo.png>])
> (./chapters/executive_summary.texpdfTeX warning (ext4): destination
> with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used,
> duplicate ignored <to be read again> 
>                    \relax  l.1 \chapter
>             *{Executive Summary} [1]
> 
> ./chapters/executive_summary.tex:1: LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
> 
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
> <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    
> 
>                                                    l.1 \chapter
>             *{Executive Summary} ) (./chapters/methodology.tex [2] Chapter 1.
> 
> Overfull \hbox (3.12325pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--5
> [][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Update 
> 
> Overfull \hbox (3.12325pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 5--5
> [][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Update  [3]
> 
> Package natbib Warning: Citation `charlotte_data_portal' on page 4
> undefined on input line 37.
> 
> 
> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 37--37
> [][][][]$\OT1/cmtt/m/n/10 https : / / data . charlottenc . gov /
> datasets / charlotte :: charlotte-[]future-[]2040-[]policy-[]map-[]4 /
> 
> Overfull \hbox (3.12325pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--37
> [][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Update 
> 
> Overfull \hbox (3.12325pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 37--37
> [][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Update 
> 
> Overfull \hbox (3.12325pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 39--39
> [][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Update 
> 
> Overfull \hbox (3.12325pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 39--39
> [][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 Update 
> 
> LaTeX Warning: Marginpar on page 4 moved.
> 
> 
> Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
> (fancyhdr)                Make it at least 21.42186pt, for example:
> (fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{21.42186pt}.
> (fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to
> compensate: (fancyhdr)               
> \addtolength{\topmargin}{-9.42186pt}.
> 
> [4 </app/graphics/C3s.png>]) (./chapters/deployment.tex
> 
> Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
> (fancyhdr)                Make it at least 21.42186pt, for example:
> (fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{21.42186pt}.
> (fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to
> compensate: (fancyhdr)               
> \addtolength{\topmargin}{-9.42186pt}.
> 
> [5] Chapter 2. [6] Overfull \hbox (124.63023pt too wide) in alignment
> at lines 42--65  [] [] [] 
> 
> Overfull \hbox (124.63023pt too wide) in alignment at lines 65--85  []
> [] [] 
> 
> Overfull \hbox (239.06099pt too wide) in alignment at lines 85--89  []
> [] [] 
> 
> Package longtable Warning: Column widths have changed (longtable)     
> in table 2.1 on input line 89.
> 
> 
> Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
> (fancyhdr)                Make it at least 21.42186pt, for example:
> (fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{21.42186pt}.
> (fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to
> compensate: (fancyhdr)               
> \addtolength{\topmargin}{-9.42186pt}.
> 
> [7]) (./chapters/call_volume_analysis.tex
> 
> Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
> (fancyhdr)                Make it at least 21.42186pt, for example:
> (fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{21.42186pt}.
> (fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to
> compensate: (fancyhdr)               
> \addtolength{\topmargin}{-9.42186pt}.
> 
> [8] Chapter 3. ) (./chapters/projected_growth.tex [9] Chapter 4. )
> (./chapters/impact.tex [10] Chapter 5. )
> (./chapters/recommendations.tex [11] Chapter 6. )
> (./chapters/conclusion.tex [12] Chapter 7. )
> (./chapters/glossary_of_terms.tex [13]) (./bibliography.tex No file
> main.bbl. )
> 
> Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
> 
> [14]
> 
> Package longtable Warning: Table widths have changed. Rerun LaTeX.
> 
> (./main.aux)
> 
> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get
> cross-references right.
> 
> 
> Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `main.out' has changed.
> (rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
> (rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.
> 
>  ) (see the transcript file for additional information)pdfTeX warning
> (dest): name{Hfootnote.2} has been referenced but does not exist,
> replaced by a fixed one
> 
> pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does
> not exist, replaced by a fixed one
> 
>  </root/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/tcrm0700.600pk>
> </root/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/tcrm0800.600pk>
> </root/.texlive2020/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/tcrm1200.600pk></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
> Output written on main.pdf (15 pages, 274850 bytes). SyncTeX written
> on main.synctex.gz. Transcript written on main.log. Latexmk: Missing
> input file: 'main.aux' from line   'No file main.aux.' Latexmk:
> Non-existent bbl file 'main.bbl in line'  No file main.bbl. Latexmk:
> References changed. Latexmk: References changed. Latexmk: Log file
> says output to 'main.pdf' Latexmk: List of undefined refs and
> citations:   Citation `charlotte_data_portal' on page 4 undefined on
> input line 37 Latexmk: Examining 'main.log'
> === TeX engine is 'pdfTeX' Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s) [bibliography.bib] Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of
> *latex:   Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s) Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):   pdflatex: Command for
> 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
>       Refer to 'main.log' for details Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,  unless error was exceeding maximum runs,
> or warnings treated as errors. Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete
> making targets

I can see that I have a bbl issue as well, however when I remove my longtable at least my document finishes compiling and I can see changes to my document.
My main.tex file is seen below:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{amsmath}      % For math
\usepackage{hyperref}     % For hyperlinks
\usepackage{geometry}     % For page layout
\usepackage{float}        % For 'Here' command for figures and tables
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
           % For strikethrough
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc} % For footnotes with symbols
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}      % For professional table formatting
\usepackage{todonotes}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\geometry{margin=1in}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=10pt} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=10pt}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
  {\thechapter.}
  {0.5em}
  {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{15pt}{30pt}  % Adjust the second value to reduce the space before the chapter title


\author{Sven Dugojevic, Carl Niedner}
\date{\today}
\vspace{3cm}

\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=.6cm]{/app/graphics/Levrum Logo.png}} 

% Footnote symbols:
% 1   asterisk        *   
% 2   dagger          †   
% 3   double dagger   ‡
% 4   section symbol  §   
% 5   paragraph       ¶   
% 6   parallel lines  ‖
% 7   two asterisks   **  
% 8   two daggers     ††  
% 9   two double daggers ‡‡
% 0   no symbol

\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\input{chapters/executive_summary.tex}
\input{chapters/methodology.tex}
\input{chapters/deployment.tex}
\input{chapters/call_volume_analysis.tex}
\input{chapters/projected_growth.tex}
\input{chapters/impact.tex}
\input{chapters/recommendations.tex}
\input{chapters/conclusion.tex}
\input{chapters/glossary_of_terms.tex}
\input{bibliography.tex}

\end{document}

I am unsure, is the citation and bibliography the root problem that is being triggered by the longtable somehow? Or is the longtable itself formatted incorrectly?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. At the moment your code is neither minimal nor does it compile, since we don't have your files. Please try to fit everything into one small example, deleting everything that is not necessary to reproduce the error.

The first error seems to concern the loss of a float following a complaint about multiple destinations with the same name. This is related to the inclusion of the title page and nothing to do with longtable. longtable isn't a float and the error occurs before it even gets to longtable. `>                    \relax  l.1 \chapter

        *{Executive Summary} [1]

./chapters/executive_summary.tex:1: LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.`


Off-topic: you are loading hyperref much too early. It needs to be loaded late.
